# How to fill up all the top of the screen with my header?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea how to fill up the space on the sides and the top of my header color like in this image : [My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t2lZ.png)

I tried to use margin but I did not find anything that's working for me, I'm new with flex and it's still a bit blurry, so I'm not sure I'll find anything by myself here either, sorry for the very basic question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <Header>
        <H1>Moi-Même</H1>
        <img src="photo-avatar-mini.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
    </Header>

    <div id="container">
        <section id="experience">
            <h2>Mon experience</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Titre 1</h3>
            <h4>entreprise</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
                reprehenderit sits.</p>
            <h3>Titre 2</h3>
            <h4>entreprise</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
                reprehenderit sits.</p>
            <h3>Titre 3</h3>
            <h4>entreprise</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
                reprehenderit sits.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="competences">
            <h2>Mes compétences</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>HTML5 et CSS3</li>
                <li>recherches <a href="https://www.google.fr/">google</a> avancé</li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>Ipsum</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="logo-html5.png" alt="html">
            <img src="logo-css.png" alt="css">
            <img src="logo-js.png" alt="js">
            <img src="logo-chrome.png" alt="chrome">
        </section>

        <section id="formation">
            <h2>Mes formations</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Titre 1</h3>
            <h4>ecole</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
            <h3>Titre 2</h3>
            <h4>ecole</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
            <h3>Titre 2</h3>
            <h4>ecole</h4>
            <h5>de 2000 a 2000</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi minus libero reiciendis. Architecto quaerat
        </section>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-family: roboto;
}

.avatar {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    background-size: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(28, 96, 141, 0.301);
}

#container {
    display: flex;
}

section {
    border-radius: 30px;;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

*edit : typo*

Comment: The `body` element has a margin by default, you can remove it with `body { margin: 0; }`.